# Changing hoverintent settings after a delay

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I'm using hoverintent for a dropdown menu and would like to like to automatically modify the interval value to something smaller after short (like 2 seconds or so) delay.

Here's the javascript I'm working with:

```
    var config = {    
     over: mousein_triger,  
     interval: 1000,   
     timeout: 100,     
     out: mouseout_triger 
};

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.panel').hide();
$("#navigation").hoverIntent(config);
$('.mncontent').focusin(function() {
        $('.panel').slideUp('fast');
    });
    $('#navigation ul li a').focus(function() {
        $('.panel').slideDown('');
    });
});

// expand the height of the container

function mousein_triger(){

    $('.panel').slideDown('');

}

// reset the height of the container

function mouseout_triger() {

$('.panel').slideUp('');

}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul id="child-navigation">
<li class="menubut"><a href="#"></a>
<ul class="panel">
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menubut"><a href="#">Get Help</a>
<ul class="panel">
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add in relevant html also?

Comment: Is there any way you can put what you have into something like jsfiddle.net just to test and play with?